# ContentEditable does not scroll till device rotation

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, scroll, contenteditable

I have a problem with an html page inside my `UIWebView`.

My Html Page have a contenteditable div

with this css

```
 #contentEditor {
            height: 98%;
            width: 98%;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
        }

body{ min-height: 100%; }
```

`contentEditor` is the identifier of the editable div.

At the first time, the html page fit the screen,

When i get the focus on the view the `UIKeyboard` appear and I resize the View.
Now, I try to scroll the div but It doesn't scroll. It scroll only if I came from portrait to landscape once again.

How can i have to do?

Edit:

I've notice one thing:

- Initially the UIWebView size is 490
- If the content fits this size and I open the keyboard to edit the content (size will be 150 now),
  the div does not scroll.
- If the content does not fit this size and I open the keyboard to edit the content (size will be 150 now), the div Will scroll.
- In the first case if I open the keyboard on a div that does not scroll and change the device rotation twice (Initially landscape --> portrait --> landscape), now the div will scroll...

I am confused